# Problem with the action bar and fragments: the app crashes when go back on a tab

Tags: android, tabs, android-3.0-honeycomb, fragment, android-actionbar

I'm new on Android and I try to make an application on Android Honeycomb 3.0
Here is my problem: I have 2 tabs in my action bar. Tab 1 uses fragments A and B and Tab 2 uses fragments C and D. When I load the application, the tab 1 is selected and fragments A and B are displayed. Then I click on tab 2 and it also works fine. But when I go back to tab 1, the app crashes and the following error is shown:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment.....
>   ..... 
>   Caused by:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #6: Duplicate
>   id 0x7f............. tag null or parent id 0x.......

here is my code:

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

       ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
       bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
       bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

       ActionBar.Tab tab1 = bar.newTab().setText("tab 1");
       ActionBar.Tab tab2 = bar.newTab().setText("tab 2");
       Fragment frag1 = new FragmentOne();
       Fragment frag2 = new FragmentTwo();
       tab1.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(frag1));
       tab2.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(frag2));
       bar.addTab(tab1);
       bar.addTab(tab2);
    }
    private class MyTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
        private Fragment mFragment;

        // Called to create an instance of the listener when adding a new tab
        public MyTabListener(Fragment fragment) {
            mFragment = fragment;
        }

        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {        
        ft.add(R.id.fragments, mFragment);  
        }

        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            ft.remove(mFragment);
        }

        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // do nothing
        }

}
```

Fragment 1:

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragments, container, false);     
        return mainView;
    }
}
```

fragments.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:name="ch.comem.test.FragmentOneA"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:id="@+id/idFragment_one_a"
           android:layout_weight="30">
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:name="ch.comem.test.FragmentOneB"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:id="@+id/idFragment_one_b"
           android:layout_weight="70">
    </fragment>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried assigning each fragment a unique tag, as suggested by the error message?

Comment: Also I assume there's a second layout XML file as the one you've included does not have a view named 'fragments'.

Comment: hi, I've tried with a unique tag on each fragment but the error persist. I've checked my XML files and no other view has been named "fragments"... Thanks for your answer

Comment: Cann you post your `main.xml`. It's not clear how you've assembled your layout without it.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue I see is that your `FragmentOne` class inflates `fragments.xml`, which itself contains references to two further fragments `FragmentOne` and `FragmentTwo`. This is not valid as Fragments can not contain other Fragments.

Comment: Thank you, it works now. I call 'fragments.xml' in the MainActivity and it works fine. But I still have one problem: now in my two tabs, I have 2 fragments each time. How can I do if I want in the first tab 1 fragment and in the second 2 fragments? Thanks for your help!